# Why I get this error? unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, selector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I want highlight text on UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669481/i-want-highlight-text-on-uiwebview)

I'm getting the error "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x756cef0" when calling `-[UIWebView highlightAllOccurencesOfString:]`. The selector was declared in WBHighlight.h and I use forward declaration in WBSecondViewController.h.

WBSecondViewController.h

```
@class WBHighlight;
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface WBSecondViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WBHighlight *webView;
- (IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)clearHighlights:(id)sender;
@end
```

WBSecondViewController.m

```
#import "WBSecondViewController.h"
#import "WBHighlight.h"
@interface WBSecondViewController ()
@end
@implementation WBSecondViewController
-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"highlighttes");
    [_webView highlightAllOccurencesOfString:@"cat"];
}

-(IBAction)clearHighlights:(id)sender{
    [_webView removeAllHighlights];
}
```

WBHighlight.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WBHighlight : UIWebView{
}
- (NSInteger)highlightAllOccurencesOfString:(NSString*)str;
- (void)removeAllHighlights;
@end
```

WBHighlight.m

```
#import "WBHighlight.h"
- (NSInteger)highlightAllOccurencesOfString:(NSString*)str
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"UIWebViewSearch" ofType:@"js"];
    NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];

    NSString *startSearch = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"uiWebview_HighlightAllOccurencesOfString('%@')",str];
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:startSearch];

    NSString *result = [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"uiWebview_SearchResultCount"];
    return [result integerValue];
}

- (void)removeAllHighlights
{
    [self stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"uiWebview_RemoveAllHighlights()"];
}
@end
```

any idea?

Comment: in your nib files, are you changing the web view object class to `WBHighlight`?

Comment: No.In WBSecondViewController.xib file the web view is connect with WBSecondViewController.h.

Comment: yes, that's ok, but you has to select the web view, go to the Identity inspector (Cmd+Option+3) and change the `Class` property from `UIWebView` to `WBHighlight`, otherwise you will be sending the message `highlightAllOccurencesOfString:` to an instance of `UIWebView` and this class do not declare this method

Comment: This is the fourth time you've posted the same question.

Comment: Hi Mr.borrrden, this question is not same question.Why you say that.

Comment: All 4 of your questions are about the exact same problem

Comment: Certainly that is same program but that error is not same.In this case, I can't post it　program never. You mean that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is due to you connected the `WBHighlight` outlet to a `UIWebView`.

Probably the `WBHighlight` is a subclassed `UIWebView` in which `highlightAllOccurencesOfString:` method is declared and defined. This method is not present in standard `UIWebView`, that's why it is throwing an error like: **unrecognized selector sent to instance**.

You need to change the class of `UIWebView` to `WBHighlight` in interface builder.

1. Go to your identity inspector
2. Select your WebView
3. Change the class of UIWebView to `WBHighlight`

[image: Class change in identity inspector]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.The program worked without error.

Answer (score 0):

Hekiru, You need to make the object of WBHighlight in order to call that method. And, for this you need to import that class and make object.

Let say,

```
WBHighlight *objWBHighlight = [WBHighlight new];

//Then, call that required method:

int someVarToAssign = [objWBHighlight highlightAllOccurencesOfString:@"fsfsf"];
```

Hope, it'll sort-out your problem.Try it.

In any concern let me know. :)